# Joining tables and leaving a column empty when the second table returns 0 row

Tags: sql, join

I want to join BUG table and FLAG table on `BUG_ID`. A BUG can have many flags, but the `FLAG_TYPE_ID` I'm looking for is, let's say 33. BUG 25000 doesn't have flag 33, so I want to leave the columns empty.

BUG table

```
BUG_ID | PRIORITY
-------+---------
25000  | High
```

FLAG table

```
BUG_ID | FLAG_TYPE_ID | STATUS
-------+--------------+--------
25000  | 44           | +
25000  | 55           | +
```

The desired join output: leaving FLAG_33_STATUS empty because bug 25000 didn't have flag 33.

```
BUG_ID | PRIORITY | FLAG_33_STATUS
-------+----------+---------------
25000  | High     |
```

If Bug 25000 had a row `FLAG_TYPE_ID` of 33 and the flag's `STATUS` was `-`, the result would have been

```
BUG_ID | PRIORITY | FLAG_33_STATUS
-------+----------+---------------
25000  | High     | -
```

I'm left at this SQL statement and I know it doesn't work and why it is so, but I don't know what I need to use.

```sql
select 
    b.bug_id, b.priority, f.status flag_33_status
from 
    bugs b
inner join 
    flag f on b.bug_id = f.bug_id and b.bug_id = 25000 and f.type_id = 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're after all the Bugs, regardless of whether they have flags, you'll probably want a LEFT JOIN between Bugs and Flags.

Then - if you only want flags of certain values - you can include that as part of the join.

So I think this will work

```
select b.bug_id, b.priority, f.status flag_33_status
from bugs b
left outer join flag f on b.bug_id = f.bug_id and f.type_id=33
where b.bug_id=25000
```

Comment: Note - your code uses `type_id` whereas your example data and explanation has `flag_type_id`. I've used `type_id` but feel free to change it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `conditional aggregation`

```
select b.bug_id, b.priority, max(case when f.type_id=33 then f.status else '-' end) flag_33_status
from bugs b
inner join flag f
on b.bug_id = f.bug_id where b.bug_id=25000
group by b.bug_id, b.priority
```